# Checking if Cookie is empty or set in php not working?

Tags: php, cookies, isset

I have some code:

```
<?php
    $cookiename1 = "uservalue";
    $cookie1 = (string)$_COOKIE[$cookiename1];
    if($cookie1 != ""){
        echo "<span style = 'color: white'>". $cookie1 . "</span>";
    }
    else{
        die("Could not get profile");
    }
?>
```

which is supposed to detect if a cookie is empty or not but when the cookie is equal to "" then it runs the echo statement.

I originally had:

```
<?php
    $cookiename1 = "uservalue";
    $cookie1 = $_COOKIE[$cookiename1];
    if(isset($cookie1) && !empty($cookie1)){
        echo "<span style = 'color: white'>". $cookie1 . "</span>";
    }
    else{
        die("Could not get profile");
    }
?>
```

But i get the same result.  Not sure what im doing wrong here =/  If anyone could help that would be awesome.

Comment: The cookie exists, but it's empty...

Comment: Yes this is correct.  I am checking if it is empty, and since it is then it should die("Could not get profile") but its instead running the echo statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

**Example:**

```
setcookie("uservalue", "some-value", time()+3600, "/", "example.com", 1);
```

After setting the cookie, you can check if it's empty:

```
if (!empty($_COOKIE["uservalue"])){
    echo "<span style='color: white'> cookie isn't empty </span>";
}
```

---

`empty` is `true` on the following conditions:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
```

Comment: Well the cookie already exists in the browser and it is set to an empty string.  And i had checked for isset and !empty in the second block of code if you didn't notice, it returned the same result as the first block.

Comment: do a `var_dump($_COOKIE["uservalue"])` what do you see ?

Comment: I see string(2) """"

Comment: nevermind i solved it by setting the cookie to 0 instead of an empty quotations value.  sorry when i said cookie = "";  then i was assuming that it was empty not that it would mean cookie = """"